# upload a file using aws sdk with out aws access key and secret key

Tags: android

My requirement is upload files into amazon s3 using AWS SDK. So for this I need aws access key and secret key.
but i have only AWSAccessKeyId and signature,policy and acl. so I want to upload using those parameter only.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, do you have an AWS account? If you have the account, on http://aws.amazon.com/ webpage,

"My Account/ Console" ->"Security Credentials", you could find your two keys.

Amazon recently use IAM, I'm not sure what is it, but if you click "access key" item, and there is a "Note" in which you could find a "Security Credentials page" link. Follow that link, you could find your keys. The Secret Access Key is hidden, so you have to click the "show" to see the key.

And A simple example how to upload file to S3.

```
public void uploadObject(String name, File file) {
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(this.bucketname, name, file);
        putObjectRequest.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
        s3.putObject(putObjectRequest); 

    }
```